# Quickly find an instance in the list with T？

Tags: c#, .net

I have a base class: Service

```
class Service {

}
```

And I have many subclasses that inherit from Service

```
class Service1 : Service { }
class Service2 : Service { }
class Service3 : Service { }
...
```

They're all in the same List

```
List<Service> services = new List<Service>() { new Service1(),new Service2(),new Service3() };
```

Because reflection cannot be used, I find it in the following method

```
    public T GetService<T>() where T : Service {
        foreach (var service in services) {
            if (service is T) return (T)service;
        }
        return null;
    }

    var instance = GetService<Service1>();
```

My question is, how can I find it as quickly as possible when there are enough elements in the list?

Comment: A simple `return services.FirstOrDefault(x => x is T);` maybe?

Comment: But that's just simpler not faster. Faster would be a hashbased list but i doubt you have thousands of Service Types where this may start to get relevant in some specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<Type,Service>` instead of a List, eg

```
class ServiceLocator
{
    private static ServiceLocator instance = new ServiceLocator();;

    Dictionary<Type, Service> services = new Dictionary<Type, Service>();

    public void Register<T>(Service service)
    {
        services.Add(typeof(T), service);
    }

    public Service GetService<T>()
    {
        return services[typeof(T)];
    }

}
```